# Calculating object's memory footprint, clarification needed

Tags: java, instrumentation

When running

```
java -javaagent:ObjectSizeFetcherAgent.jar PersistentTime
```

I get

### 24

when `ObjectSizeFetcherAgent` does this

```
public class ObjectSizeFetcher {
    private static Instrumentation  instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        instrumentation = inst;
    }

    public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

and when `PersistentTime` looks as follows

```
public class PersistentTime {

    List<String>    list    = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PersistentTime p = new PersistentTime();

        p.list.add("a");  // The number is the same with or without this
        p.list.add("b");  // The number is the same with or without this
        p.list.add("c");  // The number is the same with or without this

        System.out.println(ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(p));
    }
}
```

**Why is adding elements to the list have no affect?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PersistentTime` object consists *solely* of **one reference** (to an array list).

24 bytes is typical for objects containing a single *reference*.

Note: referenced objects are not included in the computation. `getObjectSize` is not recursively collecting the combined object sizes. This is not generally possible: there could be infinite reference loops and such; I don't think there is a "deep size" computation easily available.

Answer (score 2):

Because `getObjectSize` returns (an implementation-specific approximation of) the shallow size of the object. This means that it includes the size of the *reference* to the List, but not the space taken up by the list itself.